# sorting military time in list

Tags: list, sorting

I've created a single line of text field that's being used for storing military values (no column used). For some reason, it's sorting fine EXCEPT any value in the 1900s. Example 1942, 1900, 1925, etc. These items are not sorting properly. Any ideas?

Comment: Any screen capture? What does 'a single line of text field / no column used' mean?

Answer (score 1):

It's a normal behavior , the sort not working properly for a number value in `a single line of text field`

So if you use a custom column with `a single line of text` you can change its datatype normally from `a single line of text` to `Number`. but you should make sure that this column contains a number value to avoid conversation error. (Thanks @Eric)

[image]

**Note :**

If you use the default `title field`  , you can't change its data type, So in this case,

- you can create a `calculated field` with this formula

> `= INT([your field name])`

- Select the `Number` data type

[image]

- Go back to your view and modify it to **sort** with this `calculated field` rather than the old text field.

**Suggestion:** to avoid confusing at your view by showing two columns with the same data ,try to uncheck the `calculated field` from your view to don't display it !

Comment: Are you sure that is accurate? Example if you create a single line of text column, you can edit the field to be a number, a date, a choice, currency, or multiple lines of text. It might mangle the data in the field depending on what was there, but it will let you change the type. I've changed field types in this way (especially when dealing with Import from a spreadsheet).

Comment: @EricAlexander Yes, you are right , I talk about title field that you can change its data type because he said "no column used" that make me confused meanwhile I will update my answer to be clear for other readers, many thanks for your hint, I really appreciate :)